# extract coap query

Tags: c, http, protocols, coap

I need your help in extracting the query value in a coap message.The coap message looks like

```
coap://[ff08:90:5001:0:0:0:0:1]:12345/c?a=4
```

decoded packet is `52 02 00 00 91 63 63 61 3d 34` . Here `63 61 3d 34` is the query part `?a=4` . There is a data after query. I have pointed my buffer pointer to 63(?), now I'm struck in getting the value 34(4). How do I go to the value and extract it?

```
coap_h *hdr = (coap_h *)(buf);

buf = (uint8_t *)(hdr + 1);
len = buf[0] & 0xf;
buf += len + 1;
```

buf points to `52` initially and then I move the buf to the options field `91` and check for length then increment the buf which points to `63` (?). hope i'm clear this time.

Comment: can you show us the code please ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time at the moment to parse your packet by hand, but you should know that the way options work has changed dramatically in CoAP-12. I have implemented some functions to encode and parse options, which you might find useful:

https://github.com/darconeous/smcp/blob/master/src/smcp/coap.c

https://github.com/darconeous/smcp/blob/master/src/smcp/coap.h